# C# System media Sound Player

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use C# to play a mp3 file which is located locally, however the following code does not play sound, I can't see any problem with the code. Please help!

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer (@"/Users/Kevenliu/Desktop/Footsteps-walking-in-water.mp3");
            player.Play();
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            //System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"Users/KevenLiu/Desktop/watersimulation/Footsteps-walking-in-water.mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

The hello world showed successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you check the [SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx) class? It cannot play the `mp3` file

Comment: Has the class System.Media.SoundPlayer been removed from C# in Visual Studio 17?  I get an error when I type System.Media.

Answer (score 1):

SoundPlayer class can only be used to play files in .wav format. for MP3 you can have a look at [How to play MP3 in c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3dbfb9a3-4e14-41d1-afbb-1790420706fe/how-to-play-mp3-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

wplayer.URL = "My MP3 file.mp3";
wplayer.Controls.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

The SoundPlayer class cannot play other file types, such as .wma or .mp3. If you want to play other file types, you can use the Windows Media Player control. For more information, see Using the Windows Media Player Control in a .NET Framework Solution and Windows Media Player Object Model Reference for Visual Basic .NET and C# in the Windows Media Player SDK.

Please check the following page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx